# How can I understand bitmap photo is vertical or horizontal?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I did not find what I really need on google and stackoverflow,
I want to understand that a photo which I just capture from the camera is vertical or horizontal,
Code:

```
path_img= ("image_url");   
Bitmap  photo = null ;
photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_img );
int imageHeight = photo.getHeight();
int imageWidth = photo.getWidth();
```

When I capture the photo on my phone imageHeight and imageWidht always same I mean if I capture photo vertical or horizantal it is always 960x1280, I want to horizantal photo size is (width:960 height:1280) and vertical is (width:1280 height:960)
thanks

Comment: then you have to create another bitmap from the bitmap that you get from the camera

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) to get the orientation as the following  :

```
File imageFile = new File(imagePath);

            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            boolean isVertical = true ; 

            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    isVertical = false ; 
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    isVertical =false ; 
                    break;
            }
```

and so on for the all what you need from the Constants that are in the ExifInterface documentation .

then you can try to do somthing as the following using the [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) API :

```
int imageWidth , imageHeight = 0 ; 

if(isVertical ) {
imageWidth =1280;
imageHeight=960;
}else if (!isVertical ){
imageWidth =960;
imageHeight=1280;
}

Picasso.with(getActivity()) 
            .load(imageUrl) 
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) 
            .error(R.drawable.error) 
            .resize(imageWidth , imageHeight)
            .centerInside() 
            .into(imageView);
```

and please give me some feedback .

Hope taht helps .

Comment: the issue is how can I understand vertical or horiontal ? because I capture image to holding my phone vertical or horizontal the bitmap says always same values,

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just do a simple test of the height and width like:

```
if(imageHeight > imageWidth){
    //Image is horizontal (according to your comments, horizontal photos are usually wider than the hight)
}
elseif(imageHeight > imageWidth){
    //Image is horizontal (again, according to your comments)
}
```

Comment: imageHeight and imageWidth always are same values I mean they are 1280x960 I mean if I capture image imageWidth=1280 and weight is 960 always